# SPARQL and counting items

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm using SPARQL and Wikidata query service to try and determine: *The actors that got the Oscar award sorted by the total number of (any) awards they received in decreasing order with the list of all their awards.*

So far this is what I have that works but doesn't quite do what the question is asking.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  ?item wdt:P166 wd:Q103916 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}

LIMIT 1000
```

And this I what I have that I am trying to get to work but is not yet working. Im new to this and any help is appreciated. *Updated below query because I've gotten a bit closer*

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel (COUNT (DISTINCT ?year) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  ?item wdt:P166 wd:Q103916 .
  ?item p:P585 ?year .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
ORDER BY ?count
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: ypu have to group by the `?item` and `?itemLabel` variables

Comment: could you be more specific? ive tried flavors of this on both examples and havent gotten anything working yet